# No boot menu after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, windows-8, menu, bios

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 using a USB drive, My primary OS is Win8. After I restarted there was no option to boot into Ubuntu, it just automatically booted into Win8, even after I put the OS boot manager before the USB in the BIOS settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post. If Ubuntu is indeed installed then you may need to reinstall the grub loader: [How can I repair grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: I've heard that because Ubuntu is the second OS and not the first, I should use windows bootloader

Comment: There is no windows Bootloader, this is why it boots straight into windows. Microsoft don't "allow" dual booting. The is why you have to update the grub, to read the Ubuntu partition first (where the grub loader is stored) so it then give you the choice of what OS to boot into. GRUB is linux.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that it installed GRUB on the usb and not the hard drive, where should I put it? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: What are you options? Does it not detect automatically?

Comment: no, It doesn't, should I delete and reinstall?

Comment: can you post the o/p of `sudo fdisk -l` then we can see what partition is your Ubuntu root. I have a feeling it will be `/dev/sda1` If you know what partition it is you can follow the guide and get it installed.

Comment: Tried the reinstall, worked, Thanks for your help everybody

Answer (score 1):

You should install ubuntu after you made a free partition in win8.

You can fix it now by using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) , you can create the dual boot menu here.

Comment: The install for ubuntu created the partition for me, I set the size myself

Answer (score 0):

Welcome... I think we may need some more info to help you out.

Wich installation option did you choose while installing Ubuntu? (Erase Windows and Install Ubuntu, install Ubuntu along Windows,  etc.)
Can you see the Windows partition in the file manager?

If you can see the Windows partition but you do not have an option to boot from there, I won't be able to help you since I'm a begginer myself. If you don't see the partition, however, could it be that you erased it on a mistake?

Comment: I chose install alongside Windows, When I say I can see the partition, I mean i can see that 100 gbs of my hard drive are now gone

Comment: I'm guessing you cannot see the extra 100GBs because windows can't understand the format of the partition.(etx4)